# Error: Unsupported class file major version 64 (intelij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Trato de crear un proyecto usando spring initilizr, pero tengo un error que no puedo solucionar al momento de cargar el proyecto generado a mi IDE.

**Mi configuracion:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi estructura de proyecto:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi Gradle:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Pero al final, colo tengo el error:***Erro: Unsupported class file major version 64

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el error `Unsupported class file major version 64` indica que la `jdk 20` no es soportada. Acá la [lista de a qué version está asociada cada major version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout). basado en los screenshot que compartiste, pareciera ser que es la que tenés configurada. puede que en algún lugar de intellij te haya quedado configurada alguna versión que no es la correcta

Comment: Gracias, baje todo al 17 y me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Por acá ya respondieron https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75878942/spring-initializr-project-results-in-unsupported-class-file-major-version-64

Como tal tienes que configurar la distribución de gradle a la versión 17:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]